# How to wire a two pin bridge rectifier

Tags: bridge-rectifier

I have this bridge rectifier (Image below). https://www.deantechnology.com/products/hvhp10k

How do I wire this? I know how to wire four pin bridge rectifiers but how do I wire this two pin rectifier?

[image: Two pin bridge rectifier - HVHP10K]

Comment: It's not a bridge rectifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rectifier doesn't necessarily have to be of the bridge type. In fact, "rectifier" is basically synonymous with "diode", which is what I believe you've linked here - A diode packaged in a heatsink assembly.

From the same [website](https://www.deantechnology.com/catalog/hvca/encapsulated-rectifier-assemblies), scroll down and go to "Full Wave Bridge Rectifiers". Sounds like those are what you're after.

Comment: I see now thanks. So if I wanted to use this as a bridge rectifier I would need to use 4 of these as the diodes in a normal bridge rectifier setup?

Comment: Yep, that's my understanding - either 4 of those or a different part